# Memory Allocation without mmap2 system call strace?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, strace

Is it possible to allocate memory without the `mmap2` call?

I was working on A10 board video player, where I have a huge memory leak. possibly in each frame displayer. There is a library `libvecore` which handles system call and we don't have the source.

I know that A10 is not common subject so my question is not for A10 but for kernel memory alloc.

I try to trace the program with: `strace -e mmap2 ./VideoPlayer`.

But I'm surprised with the result. It's not calling `mmap2` while video player it calls only on startup.

But at the same time I see memory usage from `TOP` I can see VideoPlayer is contentiously allocating memory and it almost eats up 300 MB in 3 min.

So should I consider that the memory leak is in the kernel? Or there is any other call to allocate memory dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the normal way memory is allocated is via the `brk` system call.

Comment: Thanks for update. I think brk is used to realloc memory right?. I have traced brk also but there is no call of brk while playing video. Any other function ?

Comment: How are you determining that the application is allocating memory? I suspect you're wrong and the kernel is just caching data from the filesystem. The output of the `free` command is utterly useless for determining memory usage.